# xamarin.forms shell tabbar is very slow

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I'm using the shell tab bar for navigation in my application.
In the beginning, it worked perfectly, but when my application grew - it started to work slowly.

Is there an opportunity to solve the problem?

Here is my shell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Anime.Views"
       x:Class="Anime.Views.ShellView"
       Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
       StyleClass="shellStyle">
    <TabBar >
        <Tab Icon="ic_home.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomeView}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Icon="ic_search.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SearchView}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Icon="ic_person.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ProfileView}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

Comment: Based on the xaml and the little information you provided I am afraid it will be difficult for anyone to tell you what could be wrong. Keep in mind that the issue could come from Xamarin.Forms itself.

Comment: @Cfun when I had 3 pages with only 1 label on each, it worked perfectly. when I added a lot of UI components on each pages it started to work slow. Is there any way to load each page much faster?

Comment: Work slowly in which way? loading? navigating? updating ui? responding to actions?

Comment: @Cfun when I tap on tap in tab bar it freeze until the page has loaded

Comment: Only the first load of the page or even when you navigate to it after ?

Comment: @Cfun only first

Comment: You are using DataTemplate which means it will load your page only when needed, if you want it to load even before tapping than set it as a direct content, but it has a price, application starting time will increase.

Comment: @Cfun you say to use content view instead of a DataTemplate?

Comment: `<ShellContent>
<views:HomeView/>
</ShellContent>`

Comment: @Cfun I think that navigation speed improved x2, thank you. But how can I reach much speed like in youtube navigation. Should I implement some methods like OnAppear, OnDisappear etc.?

Comment: OnAppear/OnDisappear  is just an event that will be triggered when the page appears/disappears.

Comment: Are you testing on iOS or Android?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Android. I decided to refuse to use shell tabbar and changed it on sharpnado tabs, it works great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `DataTemplate` which means it will load your page only when required (when you navigate into it), if you want it to load faster (it will load during application startup) that way when you navigate into it, your page will be already loaded and ready to be displayed, then set it as a direct content, but it has a price on **your application starting time which will increase**.

Change

```
<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomeView}"/>
```

into

```
<ShellContent>
    <views:HomeView/>
</ShellContent>
```